# keras model before cloning and after cloning behaves differently

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, keras, predict, sequential

I am doing manual grid search to find the best parameters for keras model. For Every parameters combination, I check if its validation accuracy is better than the previously trained model than clone this model, so that After all combinations of parameters are checked, Model with best Validation accuracy can be used to predict on Test Set.
Question is: Why predict function behaves differently for cloned model:'

1. I run Model.fit (...)
2. Than do Model.predict (X_test) -- It gives me label Encoded output
   And:
   When I cloned this model like:
3. `BestModel = keras.models.clone_model(model.model)`
4. BestModel.predict (X_test) gives Probabilities.

p.s.: My target class is first Label Encoded then in One hot encoded form.

Answer (score 5):

Keras only copy over the structure of the model, not the weights. you will also need to copy them over. E.g.

```
BestModel.set_weights(Model.get_weights())
```